# How does Interrupts handling in IDT work and winapi tracing work in Windows?

Tags: windows, x86-64, driver, reverse-engineering, virtualization

I made my hypervisor and try to handle Exception and other calls in it.
At the moment I'm trying to handle DB exception and I don't understand the following:

This is my code:

```
case SVM::SVM_EXIT_CODE::VMEXIT_EXCP_DB:
{
    ++Counter;
    LogTraceInfo("RIP %p\n", Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rip); 
    if (Counter > 100000) { KdPrint(("OVER 100k\n")); Counter = 0; }

    Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rax = Context->Rax;
    return Status;
}
```

For example, I initialized the TF flag on the guest vm via a debugger. If I try to exit immediately after executing the first instruction, i.e. I just remove TF from the eflags register in the guest vm, then I simply do not get control back to the debugger. Hence I have a number of questions:
Is it correct that I, as it were, in DB exception, reset the TF flag when trying to stop single step tracing? There is still some RF flag, but I don't understand why it is needed and how to use it.

When tracing WinAPI I get their strange execution. For some reason, when trying to trace WinAPI again by the method above, i.e. I turn on the TF flag in the debugger and run the application via the g command in windbg. After all the actions above, most of Winapi go along their other execution branch, i.e. for some reason I can't trace them normally(I have different crashes of applications), as the same Intel PIN does.

I am just starting to study this topic (I am self-taught). I do this only out of good intentions (I am interested in various ways viruses work in order to do research on these methods and try to prevent them).

I will be glad of any help, as about the questions above, I have reached a dead end after about 2 months of trying to solve them. Thank you all in advance for reading to this end and I hope that you can help me somehow(Perhaps links to useful literature related to my questions).